# WebView Should not cover entire screen (Not showing navigation bar using navigation controller )

Tags: ios, wkwebview, swift4.1

When I load web view it is covering the entire screen

it is not displaying the navigation bar using a

navigation controller

How to display a web view with navigation bar using a navigation

controller without covering the whole screen

## Chatter Webview:

`@IBOutlet var chatterWebView: WKWebView?`

## Loading WebView :

```
 let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

chatterWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)

chatterWebView!.uiDelegate = self

 view = chatterWebView
```

## URL Request :

```
chatterWebView!.load(request as URLRequest)
```

## Navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjSye.png

this is the image which is populating, covering the entire screen.
It should fit the view controller

I have given the constraints also

Comment: set the leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of Web view from Safe Area.

Comment: I have set the constraints on that but I have figured out the solution through code 

 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
  let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier1") as!Controller

let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
 self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)